# RedirectMatch in .htaccess not working

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I am using [Transposh](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/) plugin to make my site *bilingual*. Unfortunately, despite having English as the default language and therefore available at `example.com/xxx`, Google is indexing `example.com/en/xxx`.

Until the plugin gets a fix, I am trying to use `RedirectMatch` to tell Google to index the root folder, not the `/en/` subdirectory.

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` file in the site root directory, as well as in the `.htaccess` file in the `/wordpress/` subdirectory where the WordPress installation is (as I am not sure where to put it!).

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/en/$ /
```

Is this the correct method and syntax?  It does not seem to be working.

FYI the complete `.htaccess` file in the root directory is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RedirectMatch 302 ^/en/$ /

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Why would you use `RedirectMatch` directive (from mod_alias) when you already have more powerful `RewriteRule` directives (mod_rewrite) in place? Why mix them up?

2) In any case -- your RedirectMatch rule will never be executed, since WordPress rules, the way how they done, will intercept all requests (unless, of course, if you really have `/en/` folder).

You need:

- convert rule to use `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch` (so it plays nicely with WordPress rules)
- insert such rule somewhere before/on the top of WordPress rules

Something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # your rule before WordPress rules
  RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

> I am using Transposh plugin to make my site 'bilingual'.
>   Unfortunately, despite having English as the default language and
>   therefore available at carolineelisa.com/xxx, Google is indexing
>   carolineelisa.com/en/xxx.

BTW -- in such case using canonical URLs is very recommended option (one of the reasons why it was created): http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://carolineelisa.com/testimonials/" />
```

---

Another thing -- it's better to use 301 (Permanent Redirect) response code instead of 302 (Found) for such redirects (although 302 is better for testing as it is not cached by browsers + it allows easier "recovery" in case something goes wrong (e.g. redirecting to a wrong place etc etc)).

Comment: Thank you LazyOne. The reason I was trying to use `RedirectMatch` is that I didn't really know what I was doing! I appreciate your in depth answer and I will now look into canonical URLs. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, yes, and I was using 302 as I was testing the outcome.